# Parse download of JSON data from URL

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have some JSON data which I have downloaded from a URL as *.gz* file, I then decompressed, and read the JSON as a string

I am trying to loop through the records

But neither `JArray` or `JObject` seem to work

Any ideas how to read in this data, object by object?

```
{"user_id":"25c6b8080aa26","email":"XXZZZZ@gmail.com","roles":"Manager"}
{"user_id":"1a25c6b8080b6ac","email":"XXXXX@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: When you say `and neither jArray or JObject seem to work`, can you provide the code you tried?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, you cannot de-serialize that. You are missing the starting `[`, the ending `]` and the `,` between the elements for that to be a valid array. You can use [this website](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to test the JSON string for correctness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided sample is not a valid JSON document but appear to contain snippets of JSON objects.

Assuming each record/object is confined to a single line you can read the file line by line and convert the objects

The provider data would parse to

```
public class user {
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string roles { get; set; }
}
```

And following can be used to deserialise the decompressed file

```
public class MyParser {
    public IEnumerable<T> Parse<T>(string path) {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
        foreach (var line in lines) {
            var record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(line);
            yield return record;
        }
    }
}
```

Getting the desired objects then would be something like

```
var path = "path to decompressed file";
var parser = new MyParser(); 
var users = parse.Parse<user>(path);
foreach(var user in users) {
    //...
}
```